# Creating a date object from users input

Tags: javascript, date

Trying to create a date object from a users inputted date of birth, then getDay from this date they enter:

```
MONTHS = 'JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC'; //months

var dateString = prompt('Enter your birth date in the form dd mmm yyyy','26 APR 1988'); //get users date of birth
var substrings = dateString.split(' ');
var day = substrings[0];
var month = substrings[1];
var year = substrings[2];

var pos = MONTHS.indexOf(MONTHS);
if (pos >= 0) {
}

alert(MONTHS.indexOf(month)/3);

var daysOfWeek = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
var daysOfWeek = new Date('day','month','year');
document.writeln(daysOfWeek.getDay());{
```

I'm not sure what to put in the new date object, i've tried a few things, am I totally off track?

Comment: `{` Is this a typo `document.writeln(daysOfWeek.getDay());{`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor is a bit different. Try the following:

```
var MONTHS = ["JAN", "FEB", ..., "DEC"];
var monthNum = MONTHS.indexOf(month);
var birthDate = new Date(year, monthNum, day);
```

Note that `monthNum` is zero-index (i.e. 0=Jan, 1=Feb, ..., 11=Dec).